# rsync: --fuzzy doesn't detect name changes with link-dest

Tags: rsync

So these are my test files:

```
$ ls -li live/
total 2048
804974 -rwxrwx--- 1 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:45 live/file1
804975 -rwxrwx--- 1 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:47 live/file2
```

And a first backup set:

```
$ rsync -avix live backups/1/
sending incremental file list
created directory backups/1
cd+++++++++ live/
>f+++++++++ live/file1
>f+++++++++ live/file2

$ ls -il backups/*/live/*
804981 -rwxrwx--- 1 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:45 backups/1/live/file1
804982 -rwxrwx--- 1 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:47 backups/1/live/file2
```

I rename `file1` and see if rsync can spot the renamed file with `--link-dest -fuzzy --fuzzy`:

```
$ mv live/file1 live/File1
‘live/file1’ -> ‘live/File1’

$ rsync -avHii --debug=HLINK3,FUZZY2 --link-dest=../1 --fuzzy --fuzzy live backups/2
sending incremental file list
created directory backups/2
fuzzy size/modtime match for ../1/live/file1
fuzzy basis selected for live/File1: ../1/live/file1
cd..t...... live/
>f+++++++++ live/File1
hf          live/file2

sent 1,048,997 bytes  received 188 bytes  2,098,370.00 bytes/sec
total size is 2,097,152  speedup is 2.00

$ ls -il backups/*/live/*
804981 -rwxrwx--- 1 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:45 backups/1/live/file1
804982 -rwxrwx--- 2 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:47 backups/1/live/file2
805110 -rwxrwx--- 1 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:45 backups/2/live/File1
804982 -rwxrwx--- 2 ariel ariel 1048576 Feb 22 00:47 backups/2/live/file2
```

Rsync linked `file2` so the path given to `--link-dest` is correct, and `--fuzzy --fuzzy` did match `file1` to `File1`, but it was still copied, not linked. Why?